# how to make autosuggest from mysql in gwt suggest box

Tags: java, gwt

i am new to GWT i started tutorial in google code that was working fine if i need to implement some features such as auto suggest from mysql do i need to implement the client server communication...and can any one explain with some example....

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the steps.

1. Implement the UI. Instantiate and position that [TextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html).
2. Do [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) for client/server communication.
3. Implement the server layer where you run the MySQL queries and return the answer in the GWT-RPC mechanism.
4. Add an [KeyDownHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyDownHandler.html) to your textbox.
5. Wire the key down even to the GWT-RPC call.
6. Receive the suggest result in the async callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an implementation of [SuggestOracle](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html) to request suggestions from your server. I would recommend starting with an implementation that uses [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html). When you create your [SuggestBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/index.html?overview-summary.html), pass an instance of your SuggestOracle implementation to the constructor.

For basic code samples, I would recommend Ian Bambury's [examples.roughian.com](http://examples.roughian.com/). His site has some good GWT tutorials and examples, including a [tutorial on RPC](http://examples.roughian.com/#Tutorials~RPC_To_Java)